# Android: using screenOrientation in the manifest and listening to configChanges

Tags: android, android-orientation

I have a camera app that should work in both landscape modes (normal and reverse), but should not allow portrait mode. I want to get notified when the orientation change to correct the preview. So I use both these tags

```
android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
```

and

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboard|keyboardHidden"
```

in the manifest. But whenever the first one is set, the method

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
```

simply does not get called anymore in my Activity. It does when I omit the screenOrientation tag altogether. This seems crazy, is there a way to restrict screen orientations but still have the listener triggered when they change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved with an [OrientationEventListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationEventListener.html)